# REST API URL structure

Tags: rest, api

I'm building an application in which there are `jobs` and each `job` has some `emails` sent corresponding to it.

I've got the following URL structure

```
GET /jobs    # Get all the jobs
GET /jobs/{jobId}   # Get a job by ID
GET /jobs/{jobId}/emails   # Get all emails corresponding to given job ID

POST /jobs  # Create a job
PUT /jobs/{jobId}   # To Create/update a particular job by ID
POST /jobs/_search   # To get a large number of jobs with job IDs in the request body
```

Now my question is, what should be the URL to get all the emails for a given list of job IDs?

For example. 
I use `GET /jobs` to get a list of jobs which contains the job IDs in it. Now I would like to get all the emails for the list of job IDs.

Is it a correct REST structure to use

```
POST /jobs/emails/_search    # To get all emails corresponding to each job ID in the request body
POST /jobs/emails/_count    # To get the counts of emails corresponding to each job ID in the request body
```

Or should it be just

```
POST /emails/_search
POST /emails/_count
```

Or whether both the patterns are wrong?
The first syntax seems correct to me because emails cannot exist without jobs.

The `POST` search syntax to get multiple resources is taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984477/4664244). The underscores are inspired by the [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) api.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is, what should be the URL to get all the emails for a given list of job IDs?

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.  If your API is [hypertext driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven), then clients are just following whatever links are provided by the server.

Therefore, in a REST API, the [hackable URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290007/how-would-you-design-a-hackable-url) style is [optional](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/01/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-hackable-urls/).

Using [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) for queries isn't optimal; it's not *wrong*, but it fails to describe that the query operation is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), which can be useful information for the client to have when message transport is unreliable.

It would be more common to encode the job ids into the URI in some way.  On the web, this is usually done by putting them in the query part of the URI.  It is acceptable to put them into one of the path segments instead.  You'll probably want to review your implementation's support for [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was going to use comma-separated job IDs in the `GET` call for retrieving email details. But the problem with this is that there is a limitation on the number of characters in the URL. So the `GET` call cannot be used if there are a large no.of job IDs. That is the reason I chose `POST` with search endpoint.